# How to calculate the signal x[n] when i just know its power,some character and one of its fourier series coefﬁcients?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose a periodic signal $x[n]  \xrightarrow{Fourier Series}  a_k$ has the following properties:

$a)$ Period of $x[n]$ is $8$.

$b) x[n]$ is real

$c) a_3 = 2j $

$d) \sum\limits ^{7}_{n=0} |x[n]|^2= 64$.

Find the signal $x[n]$

How do i find the signal x[n]?From here ,i just know these,the formula below, from the $a)$~$d)$

$x[n]=\sum\limits_{k}a_ke^{k \times j2\pi f n}=\sum\limits_{k \neq 3}a_ke^{k \times j2\pi f n}+2j\times e^{3 \times 2 \pi f n}=x[-n]$,and $64=(2j)^2+\sum\limits_{k\neq 3}(a_k)^2$,however,i still can't know what is the signal $x[n]$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it, but here are a few thoughts:

You have 8 numbers to find: $x[0]$, ..., $x[7]$.
The Fourier coefficients are defined as
$$a_k=\sum_{n=0}^7 x[n]e^{-2i\pi\frac{kn}8}$$
If we find those coefficients, then we can figure out the original signal, by the inverse Fourier transform
$$x[n]=\frac 1 8\sum_{k=0}^7 a_ke^{2i\pi\frac{kn}8}$$
Now since $x[0]$, ..., $x[7]$ are real, it's easy to verify that
$$a_k=a_{8-k}^\star$$
where $z^\star$ is the complex conjugate of $z$.
So we only need to find the first 5 coefficients $a_0$, ..., $a_4$, and we will derive the other 3.

Of those 5 numbers, you already know $a_3$. Still 4 to go.

Equation (d) only gives you one constraint on the Fourier coefficients (Plancherel theorem). So you're down to 3 coefficients. 
I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems that the problem is under-constrained, in that there are an infinite number of solutions.